# docker container can't connect to other container in different network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have 2 different containers running on my server(app and web_server). They are in the same network, because I put them in the same network and that network's driver is bridge.

```
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Now, I have 3rd container, which needs to connect one of the 2 containers I mentioned. I try to connect from 3rd container to 1st container like this: app:9000 , but it says host not found. I guess this is because they are in different networks. What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need both containers join the same network. either by creating a new network and make then join it or one of them join the other container's network.

the docker-compose.yml where you have `container1` and `container2`:

- define an external network which belongs to `container3`
- add one of these two containers two the external network as shown in the first snippet

the docker-compose.yml where you have `container3` will be a normal docker-compose with a bridge network.

> you need to make sure to start the third container first in order to allow the third network to be created first or you can create the third network manually using docker cli and change the definition to external

```
#docker-compose.yml

container1:
  networks:
    - first_network
    - second_network

networks:
  first_network:
    driver: bridge
  second_network:
    external: true
```

```
#docker-compose.yml
container3:
  networks:
    - second_network

networks:
  second_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: I have updated my answer. if it is not clear let me know so i can enhance it

Comment: Let's make it more simple. I have container 1 in docker-compose1.yaml and container2 in docker-compose2.yaml. they are in different network as for now. What I need is to create another network. container 2 needs to connect container 1. so which one should have bridge and which one external?

Comment: it does not matter which one will have the bridge unless you need specific one to start first. you can even create the network manually then make both containers join it

Comment: but one of them should have external right? if both have bridge, it won't work.

Comment: yes. either one of them bridge and the other one external. or both are external in case the network was previously created using `docker network create` for example

Comment: what does external mean?

Comment: external means that `docker-compose` wont try to create it. and it will only makes the container connect to it

Comment: it gives me error: Network second_network declared as external, but could not be found. even though I started other container with second_network already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189269/discussion-between-mostafa-hussein-and-nika-khurashvili).