# how to get two docker containers one running a flask service and golang services to talk to each other?

Tags: docker, go, flask, docker-compose, docker-network

I have a flask service running through docker-compose on port 5000. Similarly, I have a different go service running through another docker-compose on port 8000. The Golang service needs to call a flask API running on 5000. I am facing trouble in getting the go service to call flask service. I have tried adding docker-network but failed. What are the pros and cons of running both the services through different docker-compose as compared to single docker-compose? (I have not been able to successfully run them in a single docker-compose, btw). [docker ps running both the containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4Cms.png).

Flask Docker compose

```
version: '3'  # version of compose format

services:
  bidders:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/bidders # mount point
    ports:
      - 5000:5000  # host:container
```

Go Docker Compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  auctions:
    container_name: auctions
    build: .
    command: go run main.go
    volumes:
      - .:/go/src/auctions
    working_dir: /go/src/auctions
    ports:  
      - "8000:8000"
```

Third Nwtwork Docker-compose.yml

```
#docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

networks:
    - second_network

networks:
  second_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a single `docker-compose.yml` it will be easier to make both services inside the same network. So what was the issue you got while doing this ? Also make sure that your flask and go application both are binding to `0.0.0.0` from the code itself and not `127.0.0.1` so you can reach them from outside the container.

With two `docker-compose.yml` you have two options:

- Create a network through one of these files and make the other container which in another file join this external network.
- Create a network using `docker network create` and define an external network in both files for your containers

There is a similar question that you can check it's answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54948839/2336650) with example included

You can check [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) for more information

Comment: network-bridge is not working. both are running on 0.0.0.0 and accessible from my system individually. while making them run from a single docker-compose,I failed to run flask or go service in background, and while other service was spawning it tried to kill the other service and failed to spawn.

Comment: can you show us the error regarding this ? `network-bridge is not working`

Comment: `    networks:
      - first_network
      - second_network

networks:
  first_network:
    driver: bridge
  third_network:
    external: true
`
`
    networks:
      - second_network

networks:
  second_network:
    driver: bridge
`
I added these two the docker-compose files but still the same error that connection is refused on port 5000

Comment: I also tried to create a third docker-compose.yml for connecting these two as mentioned in the link you shared. But `ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service 'networks' must be a mapping not an array.
` this is the error thrown by that on running docker-compose up

Comment: This means you have a yaml indentation error. in the networks part in specific.

Comment: please add the full docker-compose that you have an issue with so i can guide you better

Comment: I found the intendation error you are talking about. I need to grasp the whole process a bit clearly. First, I added first_network(as bridge) and second_network(as external network) in flask docker-compose.yml. Second, I added second_network in golang docker-compose.yml(as bridge). Now I need third docker-compose.yml to connect these two, right? I ran this third container `#docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

networks:
    - second_network

networks:
  second_network:
    driver: bridge` containing this .
this stil does not work. Am I missing something?

Comment: No. I will give each network a language prefix. in flask-docker-compose.yml define two network: flask_network (bridge) and go_network (external). in go-docker-compose.yml you can define single nework called go_network (bridge) then start go-docker-compose.yml it will create the network then start flask it will join the go network

Comment: but note that docker-compose will add the current directory as a prefix

Comment: I suggest you to use one docker-compose file only. no need to use two files to avoid complexity

Comment: also the third docker-compose.yml is not correct. it will try to create a service called network. not define a network inside a container. note that the examples in the other question just a snippet not a full docker-compose

Comment: please take a look on this url there is a better explanation for the process https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: [https://github.com/thehector/bidders this is repo for code. Still the same issue. `auctions` directory is golang service. and flask service is at root. I donot understand fully where  docker-compose will add the current directory as a prefix? and its impact

Comment: try `docker-compose down && docker-compose up` then check the network that was created by docker-compose you will notice that the directory name appended to the network name as a prefix, i will check the repository.

Comment: if the answer works for you don't forget to accept and upvote it please

Comment: use the service name to call it instead of 127.0.0.1 so auctions talk to bidders through `http://bidders:5000` this will be through the docker network itself. `localhost` means inside the container only not your actual localhost that you use for development

Comment: thanks a lot for your efforts. It worked! I have a much better understanding now! 
Stackoverflow says my upvote record but not reflected here since I am new!

Comment: Glad it worked! you can mark the question as answered